# Aggregating data entries in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I really need some help finding the right Excel formula. I have multiple data entries for one day, let's say October 18th, that give me a "Start Time" and an "End Time". I want to calculate Last "End Time" - First "Start Time" for each day and that person. Here is a picture to show the data I am working with better:

[image: Picture of the data]

In short, I would like to come up with a formula that finds the last "End Time" - first "Start Time" for that person, for every day. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
=(MAX(IF((($A$2:$A$13=A2)*($C$2:$C$13=C2)),$K$2:$K$13)) - MIN(IF((($A$2:$A$13=A2)*($C$2:$C$13=C2)),$H$2:$H$13)))
```

Enter as an array formula (ctrl+shift+enter). You may need to do a little bit of fiddling with the formatting to get it to display in the format you want (my guess would be you want the number of hours & minutes between the greatest end value and the smallest start value, but I am not 100% sure of that). You can start with multiplying the result by 24 to give you the number of hours and minutes (in decimal format - 8.35 would be 8 hours, 21 minutes).

[image]

Comment: The easy way to get hours and minutes is to format the “Difference” column as a time (`h:mm`). That way, 8.35 will be displayed as `8:21`. (You don’t need to do any arithmetic.)

Comment: Referring to the answer above, what formula could I use to sort through the duplicate data in Column M? My goal is to sum those hours for a total hours worked in the week. Having three cells in column M reading "8.35" for 10/18/2016 makes that troublesome. Thanks

Comment: Also, for some reason, when I copy and paste the formula given by Joe into my sheet with the same exact data, it reads "0". I checked formatting and also entered the equation as an array.